# How to only include cited reference and exclude the non cited one?

Tags: bibliographies, texmaker, jabref

The `.bib` file contains all references, but I only cited part of them in my report. I used the following code, and it appears that all references in the `.bib` show in the bibliography section. I am wondering that how to only include the cited reference into the bibliography? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

\section{My report}

\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{time series} %name of the .bib

\end{document}
```

I did use `\nocite` before, but I then deleted it, and the bibliography section still show all reference.

Comment: Normally, it's the default. You have to ask for including non-cited references with `\nocite{*}`. Unless the `chicago` style includes this command?

Comment: Did you rerun BibTeX after removing `\nocite` and did you compile twice afterwards?

Comment: it might work if you are lucky but I would not put a space in your bib file name.

Comment: I suspect the same as @cfr

Comment: @cfr Thanks! It works! I did not realise that I need to run BibTeX again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments